# HTML display:grid not configuring columns

Tags: html

Right, this has got to be the world must idiotic thing I have ever come across. Why - despite following the tutorial on here to the letter - can I not get the below into four columns?

Absolutely ridiculous.

```css
footer {
    background-color: #000861;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

footer div{
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="">Text</div>
    <div class="">Text</div>
    <div class="">Text</div>
    <div class="">Text</div>
    <div class="">Text</div>
    <div class="">Text</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `grid-template-columns` inside the footer instead

```css
footer{
    background-color: #000861;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

}

footer div{
    border: solid 2px #fff;  
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <div class="">Text</div>
        <div class="">Text</div>
        <div class="">Text</div>
        <div class="">Text</div>
        <div class="">Text</div>
        <div class="">Text</div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Bloody ridiculous. thank you, much appreciated, but bloody ridiculous. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` css property to your `footer` break it into column

P.S

You can use any number instead 4

Comment: Yes, the way I have done this has always worked, not today, it decided it's going to have a mind of it's own and not do as it's told. It's just hilarious how my time si dictated by a piece of software with clearly a mind of its own.